# Enforcing that a Dart type implements an interface

Tags: types, interface, dart

I have a map of strings to types in Dart e.g. `animals = <String, Type>{'cat':CatType, 'dog':DogType}` which I modify at runtime. Is there a way to ensure that types added to this map implement a particular interface, either at compile-time or runtime? Something like

```
animals = <String, Type<? implements AnimalType>>{...}
```

or during runtime,

```
void register(name, type):
  if type implements AnimalType:
    animals[name] = type
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not really.

The `Type` class isn't generic, so you can't have a constrain on that.

You can use the `dart:mirrors` library to check whether a `Type` object represents a class that implements another type, but it's most likely not worth the effort.